# Redirect all error warnings so they print somewhere else

Tags: python, user-interface, exception, terminal

I am currently making a program with a GUI and an integrated terminal.I can write to this terminal using the function `write_to_terminal(str)` I am wondering, if an exception is raised within the program, is there any way I can simply redirect the output from the exception so that it prints on the integrated terminal?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
try:
    #do something that might cause error
except Error_to_catch as str:
    write_to_terminal(str)
    #pass if needs to or what not
```

Calling the function to handle the except is a pretty standard thing. that is if your `write_to_terminal(str)` works